# Check for existence of array of files

Tags: matlab, file-exists

I have a cell array containing file names. I want to check for the existence of all of these files in the subject folder, and if any one does not exist I wish to send a continue to the top-most for-loop (see mock code). Is there a way to do this in a one or two liner, instead of 1) using a for-loop and a double if-statement, or 2) building a function that for-loops over exist().

```
subjects = {'/data/subject01','/data/subject02','/data/subject03'};
files = {'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'};
for ii = 1:numel(subjects)
    for jj = 1:numel(files)
        fileExists = exist([subject{ii} '/' file{jj}],'file')
        if ~fileExists
            continue
        end
    end
    if ~fileExists
        continue
    end
    % Some code to execute if all files exist.
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*fun` functions are just loops internally and are generally slower than the explicit loop. They also very often unnecessarily obfuscate the intent and behavior of the code.

You can use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with [`all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) and [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to make the approach clearer and remove the unnecessary loop:

```
subjects = {'./data/subject01','./data/subject02'};
files = {'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'};

for ii = 1:numel(subjects)
    filelist = dir(fullfile(subjects{ii}, '*.txt'));
    foundfilenames = {filelist(:).name};
    if all(ismember(files, foundfilenames))
        fprintf('All %u files are here: %s\n', numel(files), subjects{ii})
    else
        fprintf('All %u files are not here: %s\n', numel(files), subjects{ii})
    end
end
```

With my folder structure:

```
/data
  /subject01
    a.txt
    b.txt
  /subject02
    a.txt
    b.txt
    c.txt
```

I see the following, as expected:

```
All 3 files are not here: ./data/subject01
All 3 files are here: ./data/subject02
```

Comment: Thanks! That indeed looks a lot neater.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the loop by iterating over all combinations of the two arrays:

```
subjects = {'/data/subject01','/data/subject02','/data/subject03'};
files = {'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'};
a=numel(subjects);
b=numel(files);
k=a*b;
paths = arrayfun(@(ii)[subjects{mod(ii-1,a)+1} '/' files{ceil(ii/b)}],1:k,'uniformoutput',0);
checkExist = cellfun(@exist, paths, repmat({'file'},1,k));
if all(checkExist)
    % Some code to execute if all files exist
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it with a cellfun and by string arrays. Technically there is still a for-loop but it resolves the double if-statement. I will leave this question open for better solutions.

```
subjects = {'/data/subject01','/data/subject02','/data/subject03'};
files = string({'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'});
for ii = 1:numel(subjects)
    paths = subject{ii} + files;
    checkExist = cellfun(@exist, cellstr(paths), repmat({'file'},size(paths))
    if ~all(checkExist(:))
        continue
    end
    % Some code to execute if all files exist.
end
```